# (Importance of) Existence of continuous section

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, continuity

For a continuous surjection between topological spaces $f\colon X \to Y$, how hard usually is to settle down conditions for the existence of a continuous section $s\colon Y \to X$ (a continuous mapping s.t. $f\circ s = \text{Id}_Y$)?

I've seen the existence of such section proven in the context of profinite groups, when $f$ is a continuous homomorphism. But the proof, though, intrinsically uses the group and the inverse limit structure of the domain.

Given that AC actually could provides us with a ton of possible sections, how comes one needs so much more to force the existence of a continuous one? For topological spaces alone, I know they don't always exist (taking $X = Y$ non-empty sets, one with discrete topology and the other one with the trivial topology, the identity function is continuous one way but it's only section isn't).

When we work with onto mappings, it's always natural to consider sections. And because staying in the same category is always nice, continuous sections are also natural to consider. Their general existence is well-understood? Is at least as desirable and useful as intuition tells me?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the existence of a continuous section is a very strong condition. It should imply that $f$ is a quotient mapping; but, most quotient mappings don't have this property. For example, the map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$ that wraps you around the unit circle repeatedly is a quotient mapping with no section.